Windows exhibit multiple child/sub processes in Task Manager
I have a Python application that I'm running as a service using the pywin32 library. I have multiple Windows 10 servers, each hosting around ten Python services running the same code on different ports for load balancing.
During the testing phase, I noticed an unexpected behavior in Task Manager. When monitoring the memory usage of each Python service, I observed that they appear to have multiple child/sub processes. This behavior is inconsistent, as sometimes no child/sub processes are visible at all. Additionally, I noticed processes like GoogleUpdater Internal Service and Delivery Optimization under Python services, which I'm not creating or using.
Here are some screenshots illustrating the issue:
showing-multiple-process-under-python-service
2. showing-multiple-process-under-python-service
It is important to note that, when I close and reopen the Task Manager, the processes appear as expected with no child/sub process. Please ignore the highlighted PID in the screenshot as it is for internal reference.
no-child-process
NOTE: This behavior is observed on multiple Windows servers. Upon reopening Task Manager, the processes appear as expected.
Could someone please explain why this issue occurs initially in Task Manager and why it disappears upon reopening?
Thanks
I checked the code, everything looks fine. There are no functionality issue found in the application.
